# pandoc.exe: Data.Binary.Get.runGet at position 0: not enough bytes

Tags: ms-word, pandoc

I use to convert my text file into Word (or any other format like PDF) file using [Pandoc](http://www.pandoc.org/) 
with this command

```
pandoc -s abc.txt -o abc.docx
```

but since yesterday i am getting this error when i try to convert into word file i get this error

```
 pandoc.exe: Data.Binary.Get.runGet at position 0: not enough bytes
```

it work fine when i try to convert into PDF  and other format but it stop working for DOCX (word file )

I tried to google but no help on it :(

Comment: I get the same error (with a different position value) when I try to produce javascript from haskell source with haste.